Issue converting struct to parquet using xitongsys/parquet-go ( runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference )
The timestamp in my struct is causing the following error:
runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

The struct is:
type MyTs struct {
    time.Time
}

func (myts *MyTs) UnmarshalJSON(d []byte) error {
    str := string(d)
    str = str[1 : len(str)-1] // Remove the surrounding double quotes

    // Define the time layouts
    layout1 := "2006-01-02T15:04:05+0000"
    layout2 := "2006-01-02T15:04:05.999999Z"

    // Try parsing with the first layout
    t, err := time.Parse(layout1, str)
    if err != nil {
        // If the first layout fails, try the second layout
        t, err = time.Parse(layout2, str)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }

    myts.Time = t
    return nil
}

func (myts *MyTs) String() string {

    stringTime := fmt.Sprintf("%d", myts.Time.UnixNano()/1000000)

    res := fmt.Sprintf("{Time:%s}", fmt.Sprint(stringTime))

    return res
}

type StructData struct {
    ID        string `bson:"id" json:"id" parquet:"name=id, type=BYTE_ARRAY, convertedtype=UTF8, encoding=PLAIN_DICTIONARY"`
    Timestamp MyTs   `parquet:"name=timestamp, type=INT64, logicaltype=TIMESTAMP_MILLIS"`
}

If I comment out Timestamp in StructData then the function to write to parquet works with no issues.
The result does not have to be in TIMESTAMP_MILLIS - if the solution requires a different type in the output then that is fine
go.mod:
require (
    github.com/xitongsys/parquet-go v1.6.2
    github.com/xitongsys/parquet-go-source v0.0.0-20200817004010-026bad9b25d0
)

any help is greatly appreciated

fbts.Time = t did you mean to use myts.Time = t? (it's unclear what fbts is). The error should provide more info (i.e. a pointer towards the specific line that caused the panic).

@Brits sorry, that was a typo in copying the code, it is myts.Time = t
